# App Engine standard build on Cloud Build with npm@7

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm, google-cloud-platform, dependencies

I have monorepo setup and upgraded from **yarn** 2 to **npm** 7.
Was working perfectly fine till I tried to deploy my application to the standard app engine environment.

`gcloud app deploy` kicks off a build inside Cloud Build, which builds my project via buildpacks ([nodejs14 buildpack](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/tree/main/builders/gae/nodejs14)).

My problem is, that this buildpack includes nodejs14 and npm@6 and without using the flex environment it doesn't seem that there is a way to use npm@7 in this standard app engine cloud build.

What I've tried by now:

1. Use same OS and install `node_modules`, tar them, upload them, untar them. (could not really do it)
2. Link packages locally before uploading (don't know if I did that right. App was not finding local packages afterwards)
3. Trying to use a `cloudbuild.yaml`, but it seems that this is not possible with standard environment.
4. in the custom build step `"gcp-build": "npm i -g npm@7"` (does not work, permission error, see full build log [here](https://easyupload.io/fljqpe))

I would really appreciate every pointer in any direction that could help me out.

This is my **project setup**:

```
[project]/
 ├── packages/
 │    ├── app
 │    │    ├── node_modules/
 │    │    ├── src/
 │    │    ├── app.yaml
 │    │    ├── ...
 │    │    └── package.json
 │    ├── shared
 │    │    ├── node_modules/
 │    │    ├── src/
 │    │    ├── ...
 │    │    └── package.json
 │    ├── shared-admin
 │    │    ├── node_modules/
 │    │    ├── src/
 │    │    ├── ...
 │    │    └── package.json
 │    ├── base-server
 │    │    ├── node_modules/
 │    │    ├── src/
 │    │    ├── ...
 │    │    └── package.json 
 ├── package.json
 │ 
 └── node_modules/
```

Comment: In number 4, can you give the exact error?

Comment: Here is the whole build log in a txt file https://easyupload.io/fljqpe

Comment: have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66057039/8753991)? It seems combination of 1 and 4.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly the one I tried, but the problem was that with npm@7 you have multiple node_modules and in the root you have like all of them, that are shared across the project and in the project scope the ones that are only needed in each project. 
With npm@6 you can only view the root ones in each project folder, meaning that you would have to duplicate all node_modules in each project folder.
I don't know but it did not work properly for me.